# Get a Vector2 Based on Object Rotation in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, vector

I feel like there is an obvious answer to this but I can't find it. Is there a function in unity that gives you a Vector2 (or 3) based on the rotation of an object.

for example:

z rotation = 0 ---> (0,-1)
z rotation = 90 --> (1,0)
z rotation = 180 -> (0,1)
z rotation = 270 -> (-1,0)

I could just write this in my script the long way, but I feel like there might be a function for it in unity

Comment: The usual mathematical convention is to start at (1, 0) and go counter-clockwise from there, which slightly complicates the mapping you've shown, since you have a different starting point. Do you need this only for integer multiples of 90 degrees, or also for intermediate angles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an object whose transform is already rotated the way you want on the z axis (and not rotated on the x and y), then this is as simple as:

```
Vector2 direction = -transform.up;
```

Otherwise, you can construct the rotation you want and rotate the "down" vector by it:

```
Vector2 RotationToVector(float degrees) {

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, degrees);
    Vector2 v = rotation * Vector3.Down;

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to make it the other way around ? (vector --> rotation)

Comment: As a quaternion: `Quaternion.LookRotation(vector, Vector3.back) * Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0);` As an angle (in radians): `Mathf.Atan2(vector.x, -vector.y);` Don't forget to put your full question in your original post next time. 